# moneybookers getting params from cancel_url

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am integrating my system with moneybookers and I have one question. Is it possible to get a `transaction_id` from a `cancel_url`? Does anybody know if `cancel_url` comes with any parameters like `return_url` (moneybookers documentation says nothing about it)? I need this because I want to show the user for which payment the problem occurred.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought not because if the user cancels, then there's no transaction.

This falls on your side, where you'll need to create an order in your database when a user clicks checkout, and then have your Moneybookers callback update the order based on the order ID.

With *PayPal*, you can send custom fields with a payment request which is commonly used to send the order ID on your site; I assume there's something similar with Moneybookers.